# Using arrays and macros in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a QA.  I'm not a developer, but I asked my boss for some busy work.  She gave me a development project, and I'm completely confused.  We have a spreadsheet with a long list of salespeople and their customers.  For each customer, the salesperson, customer name, sales amount, and location are listed like so:

```
Salesperson    Customer Name    Sales Amount   Location

salesperson1   customerA        3456789        Atlanta

salesperson1   customerB        9475903        Atlanta

salesperson1   customerC        7236433        Atlanta

salesperson1   customerD        9809489        Raleigh

salesperson2   customerA        3456789        Raleigh

salesperson2   customerB        9475903        Raleigh

salesperson2   customerC        7236433        Raleigh

salesperson2   customerD        9809489        Raleigh

salesperson2   customerE        3456789        Raleigh

salesperson3   customerA        9475903        Portland

salesperson3   customerB        7236433        Portland

salesperson3   customerC        9809489        Portland

salesperson4   customerA        9475903        Portland

salesperson4   customerB        7236433        Portland

salesperson4   customerC        9809489        Portland
```

There are hundreds of lines of salespeople and customers on this spreadsheet.  My job is to create a new workbook template.  I have successfully done that.  The template takes relative sales data and does calculations based on sales numbers.  Currently, I've been able to get all of the data from the source in to the template, and the calculations work.  However, I need to go further.  For each salesperson, I need there data loaded on to a separate sheet, and I need a separate template for each location.  For example:  notice that salesperson3 and salesperson 4 are in the Portland location.  I need a separate sheet for salesperson3 and a separate sheet for salesperson4 on the same workbook which needs to be saved as PORTLAND.XLSM.  There will also need to be a template called RALEIGH.XLSM and ALTANTA.XLSM.

So here are my questions:

1. How do I make an array to notice when I go from salesperson1 to salesperson2 to salesperson3 to salesperson4?
2. How do I do an array that will eliminate anyone not at that location?  I presume I will need a worksheet for each location, and if the name of the worksheet doesn't match the location of that salesperson, that salesperson doesn't get a sheet in that workbook.

I haven't used VB since I was in college almost 2 decades ago.  I know the logic, but I don't know the language and syntax.

Comment: This is a great job for an Access database. if you are going to dive head deep into making this logic work in Excel, however daunting Access seems it will be a lot easier than Excel.

Comment: If its syntax thats tripping you up you can always use the record macro tool and see the syntax it produces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brad mentioned this is going to be a beast to maintain. That being said, if I understand your question correctly, I'd use the .Range() function. If you have your data in a table you can pull an array and do what you're looking for with this function.

```
Public Sub createSheets()
    Dim salespersons As Range, location As String, fileLocation As String, salesperson As String, newSheet As Worksheet

    Set salespersons = Range("Table1[Salesperson]")

    For i = 1 To salespersons.Count
        location = salespersons(i).Offset(0, 3).Value
        If i = 1 Or (salespersons(i).Offset(0, 3).Value <> salespersons(i - 1).Offset(0, 3).Value) Then
            Call createBook(location)
        End If
    Next i
    For Each wbook In Application.Workbooks
        For i = 1 To salespersons.Count
            If i = 1 Or (i > 1 And salespersons(i) <> salespersons(i - 1)) Then
                salesperson = salespersons(i).Value
                location = salespersons(i).Offset(0, 3).Value

                If location & ".xlsx" = wbook.Name Then
                    If i = 1 Or (salespersons(i).Value <> salespersons(i - 1).Value) Then
                        On Error Resume Next
                        Set newSheet = wbook.Worksheets(salesperson)
                        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                            Set newSheet = wbook.Worksheets.Add
                            newSheet.Name = salesperson
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub createBook(location As String)
    Dim newBook As Workbook, newSheet As Worksheet, result1 As Boolean, result2 As Boolean


    result1 = isWorkbookOpen(location & ".xlsx")

    If result1 = False Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Workbooks(location).Save
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Workbooks.Open (location & ".xlsx")
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Workbooks.Add.SaveAs (location & ".xlsx")
                Error Err.Number
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function isWorkbookOpen(location As String)
    Dim ff As Long, Errno As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open Filename For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    Errno = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case Errno
        Case 0:
            isWorkbookOpen = False
        Case 70:
            isWorkbookOpen = True
        Case 75:
            isWorkbookOpen = False
        Case Else: Error Errno
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: smcjones, is there any way i can contact you?  i'd like it if you could walk me through this.

Answer (score 0):

This will loop over a source sheet (the active sheet) and generate a number of workbooks (one per location). A sheet containing customer name and sales amount for each sales person is added to the workbook.

once the workbooks are generated it saves them as their location's name.

```
' get a named worksheet from specified workbook, creating it if required
Public Function GetSheet(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Book As Workbook, Optional ByVal Ignore As Boolean = False) As Worksheet
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Key As String
Dim Result As Worksheet: Set Result = Nothing

    Key = UCase(Name)

    ' loop over all the worksheets
    For Each Sheet In Book.Worksheets
        ' break out of the loop if the sheet is found
        If UCase(Sheet.Name) = Key Then
            Set Result = Sheet
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Sheet

    ' if the sheet isn't found..
    If Result Is Nothing Then
        If Ignore = False Then
            If Not GetSheet("Sheet1", Book, True) Is Nothing Then
                ' rename sheet1
                Set Result = Book.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                Result.Name = Name
            End If
        Else
            ' create a new sheet
            Set Result = Book.Worksheets.Add
            Result.Name = Name
        End If
    End If

    Set GetSheet = Result

End Function


Sub Main()
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Location As Workbook
Dim Sales As Worksheet
Dim LocationKey As String
Dim SalesKey As String
Dim Index As Variant
Dim Map As Object: Set Map = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim Row As Long

    Set Source = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    Row = 2 ' Skip header row

    Do
        ' break out of the loop - assumes that the first empty row signifies the end
        If Source.Cells(Row, 1).Value2 = "" Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        LocationKey = Source.Cells(Row, 4).Value2

        ' look at the location, and find the workbook, creating it if required
        If Map.Exists(LocationKey) Then
            Set Location = Map(LocationKey)
        Else
            Set Location = Application.Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
            Map.Add LocationKey, Location
        End If

        SalesKey = Source.Cells(Row, 1).Value2

        ' get the sheet for the salesperson
        Set Sales = GetSheet(SalesKey, Location)

        ' insert a blank row at row 1
        Sales.Rows(1).Insert xlShiftDown

        ' populate said row with the data from the source
        Sales.Cells(1, 1).Value2 = Source.Cells(Row, 2)
        Sales.Cells(1, 2).Value2 = Source.Cells(Row, 3)

        'increment the loop
        Row = Row + 1
    Loop

    ' loop over the resulting workbooks and save them - using the location name as file name
    For Each Index In Map.Keys
        Set Location = Map(Index)
        Location.SaveAs Filename:=Index
    Next Index

End Sub
```

**Update**

This code is only really helpful if you are generating read-only reports, that get replaced every time you generate the report. (this code will probably fail to save on subsequent runs as it does not check to see if a file exists when trying to save, you'll need to delete any previous output before running it again).

This code (in its current form) would need to be added into the workbook with your source data, and the data sheet would need to be active before you run the `Main()` macro.

If you are trying to do more than just generate a report (like replacing the source data sheet with your new files)  it would be much simpler in Access as a few people have already suggested.

Comment: interesting.  i will study this one.

Comment: So . . . . if the source spreadsheet is "s:\qa\salesbudgeting\target.xlsx" where would I put that in this code?  And would this be a separate spreadsheet that once opened would generate these?  I apologize, but I am truly ignorant on this project.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  So i can just add this to the current source data sheet and edit it as necessary to pull the correct cells (because there is additional information on the source)?

Comment: Yes, you can include any extra columns from the source by editing the code below the "populate said rows" comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using pivot tables that requires NO VBA.  If you use this, maintenance takes a little more work, but it's very simple to set up and hand off:

1. From your source, make a pivot-table and add it to a new document.
2. For your **Report Filter**, add the *SalesPerson* and *Location*. Leave the actual dropdowns at (All) for now or just pick values at random.
3. For your **Row label**, you can add the *Customer*.
4. For your **Values**, you can sum your sales amounts.
5. Make the tab as pretty as you like.  This will be your template for all the sales people.  The **Options ribbon** lets you add custom calcuations, % of row totals, etc. Go wild. You now have a tab which can serve as a template for every salesperson!
6. Make a blank workbook for each location.  For each location's workbook, add this template tab for each salesperson that works there.  In that tab's pivot table's filters, pick the location and a salesperson.
7. Repeat #6 until each workbook has a tab for each salesperson and each of those tabs has the proper salesperson and location selected.

Yes, that was monotonous, but now you're done with the hard part!  Every salesperson has their own tab and every location has their own file.  Thanks to the report filters in the many, many tabs you've just made, each tab is filtered to just the sales in that location for that salesperson.

#### Updating the data:

The biggest drawback to this option is that everytime a SalesPerson starts selling at a new location, or a new SalesPerson is hired, you'll have to add a new tab. But thanks to your common template tab, this isn't very painful.

For regular updates, just open each file and go to the **Data** ribbon and **Refresh all**.